# Flutter error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, typeerror

I am using a dropdownbuttonfield and getting this error:

```
A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'String'.dart(invalid_assignment)
```

Code :

```
    class SettingsForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsFormState createState() => _SettingsFormState();
}

class _SettingsFormState extends State<SettingsForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final List<String> sugars = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'];
  final List<int> strengths = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900];

  // form values
   String? _currentName;
   String? _currentSugars;
   int? _currentStrength;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MyUser user = Provider.of<MyUser>(context);

    return StreamBuilder<UserData>(
        stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            UserData? userData = snapshot.data;
            return Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Update your brew settings.',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                  TextFormField(
                    initialValue: userData!.name,
                    decoration: textInputDecoration,
                    validator: (val) =>
                        val!.isEmpty ? 'Please enter a name' : null,
                    onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentName = val),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  DropdownButtonFormField(
                    value: _currentSugars ?? userData.sugars,
                    decoration: textInputDecoration,
                    items: sugars.map((sugar) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: sugar,
                        child: Text('$sugar sugars'),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentSugars = val), <--Error here **val** right one
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  Slider(
                    value: (_currentStrength ?? userData.strength).toDouble(),
                    activeColor:
                        Colors.brown[_currentStrength ?? userData.strength],
                    inactiveColor:
                        Colors.brown[_currentStrength ?? userData.strength],
                    min: 100.0,
                    max: 900.0,
                    divisions: 8,
                    onChanged: (val) =>
                        setState(() => _currentStrength = val.round()),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                      style:
                          ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.pink[400]),
                      child: Text(
                        'Update',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(
                              _currentSugars ?? snapshot.data!.sugars,
                              _currentName ?? snapshot.data!.name,
                              _currentStrength ?? snapshot.data!.strength);
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        }
                      }),
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Loading();
          }
        });
  }
}
```

[Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mF6pr.png) [Update 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1oiV.png)
A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'String'.

Comment: pls do mention the type of `_currentSugars` and `sugars`.

Comment: @TheAlphamerc they are both 'Strings'

Comment: @MikeOsborn Just set `_currentSugars = val!`

Comment: @MidhunMP the error doesn't change

Comment: do you want an update screenshot?

Comment: @MikeOsborn What is the error you are getting now?

Comment: @MidhunMP same error I have two 'val' and they are both objects and I think they should both be 'strings' and dynamic

Comment: @MikeOsborn My above comment is for your current screenshot and for the error `'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'`

Comment: no it's not the same code

Comment: @MidhunMP pls see the update 2 screenshot

Comment: You need to change `DropdownButtonFormField` to `DropdownButtonFormField<String>` then use my above mentioned comment

Comment: Wait I didn't have to put the exclamation mark, it worked just by putting "<String>  but since you solved my previous problem by "String? _currentSugars;" it now works without null check.

Comment: @MikeOsborn Yeah, since you declared it as nullable, so you no longer need to use !.

Comment: @MidhunMP Can u solve this q also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68460812/flutter-error-could-not-find-the-correct-providermyuser-above-this-settingsfo Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to give `val` as a String, or any type you want to to become:

```
onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentSugars = val as String),
```

Answer (score 4):

Assign the generic type `String` to the DropdownButtonFormField:

```
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                    value: _currentSugars,
                    decoration: textInputDecoration,
                    items: sugars.map((sugar) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: sugar,
                        child: Text('$sugar sugars'),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentSugars = val), 
                  ),
```

Unless you specify the type `String` dart makes the assumption with the one of the most generic types it has `Object?` as the generic type of the `DropdownButtonFormField`

#### Complete demo (Updated to use null safety)

```
class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  Demo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DemoState createState() => _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  final sugars = ['candy', 'chocolate', 'snicker'];
  String? _currentSugars = 'candy';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
          value: _currentSugars,
          items: sugars.map((sugar) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(
              value: sugar,
              child: Text('$sugar sugars'),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentSugars = val),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It does work for me, I added a demo in which I declare both `_currentSugars` and `sugars` which are the only to unknowns to me from the code you posted

Comment: updated it. I forgot about null safety 

Comment: can you tell the difference and see what's causing the error

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue.

```
onChanged: (val) => setState(() => 
    _currentSugars = val as String
    ),
```

You can use as String after the val.
if your using int value you can use `as int` as well.