# Flutter Error : The left operand can't be null, so the right operand is never executed. Try removing the operator and the right operand

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

I am trying to build my flutter project but I get an error while using the ternary operator.
I am using the ternary operator because it would check if the first statement is null, if it is null then it's going to use the second statement. This helps me with my code but I am getting an error, it states :

**The left operand can't be null, so the right operand is never executed. Try removing the operator and the right operand.**

Example:

```
value: initial_value ?? current_value
```

Code :

```
class SettingsForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsFormState createState() => _SettingsFormState();
}

class _SettingsFormState extends State<SettingsForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final List<String> sugars = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'];
  final List<int> strengths = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900];

  // form values
  late String _currentName;
  late String _currentSugars;
  late int _currentStrength;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MyUser user = Provider.of<MyUser>(context);

    return StreamBuilder<UserData>(
        stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            UserData? userData = snapshot.data;
            return Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Update your brew settings.',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                  TextFormField(
                    initialValue: userData!.name,
                    decoration: textInputDecoration,
                    validator: (val) =>
                        val!.isEmpty ? 'Please enter a name' : null,
                    onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentName = val),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  DropdownButtonFormField(
                    value: _currentSugars ?? userData.sugars, <--Error : **userData.sugars**
                    decoration: textInputDecoration,
                    items: sugars.map((sugar) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: sugar,
                        child: Text('$sugar sugars'),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentSugars = val),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  Slider(
                    value: (_currentStrength ?? userData.strength).toDouble(), <--Error : **userData.strength**
                    activeColor:
                        Colors.brown[_currentStrength ?? userData.strength], <--Error : **userData.strength**
                    inactiveColor:
                        Colors.brown[_currentStrength ?? userData.strength], <--Error : **userData.strength**
                    min: 100.0,
                    max: 900.0,
                    divisions: 8,
                    onChanged: (val) =>
                        setState(() => _currentStrength = val.round()),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                      style:
                          ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.pink[400]),
                      child: Text(
                        'Update',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(
                              _currentSugars ?? snapshot.data!.sugars, <--Error : **snapshot.data!.sugars**
                              _currentName ?? snapshot.data!.name, <--Error : **snapshot.data!.name**
                              _currentStrength ?? snapshot.data!.strength); <--Error : **snapshot.data!.strength**
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        }
                      }),
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Loading();
          }
        });
  }
}
```

'MyUser' data class :

```
class UserData {

  final String uid;
  final String name;
  final String sugars;
  final int strength;

  UserData({ required this.uid, required this.sugars, required this.strength, required this.name });
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3RVU.png) [Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pPij.png)

Comment: how about using `_currentSugars!=null? _currentSugars: userData.sugars `

Comment: You declared `_currentSugars` as non nullable. Declare it as `String? _currentSugars;`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Yeah but it show blue line relating unnecessary null comparison : "The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true.
Remove the condition."

Comment: its; ok to use like this, but message is showing because your `currentSugars`  will never receive null value, also you can remove conditional statement.

Comment: @MidhunMP it says: "Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'.
Try changing the condition." and the same error: "The left operand can't be null, so the right operand is never executed.
Try removing the operator and the right operand."

Comment: @MikeOsborn Could you please show how you changed the condition and how you declared that variable now ?

Comment: Yea see my update screenshot

Comment: @MikeOsborn I mean variable declaration. Instead of `late String _currentSugars; ` declare it as `String? _currentSugars;`

Comment: Bruh it also works

Comment: Anyway thanks for the help

Comment: @MidhunMP can you also answer this question if you want to.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68449448/flutter-error-a-value-of-type-object-cant-be-assigned-to-a-variable-of-typ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've declared the `_currentSugars` variable as a non-nullable string. So you are explicitly stating that it cannot contain a null value. By adding late keyword to that, compiler can't ensure the null-safety constraint at compile time.

As per [late-variables](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-variables)

> The late modifier means “enforce this variable’s constraints at
> runtime instead of at compile time”

So instead of declaring it as:

```
late String _currentSugars;
```

Declare it as:

```
String? _currentSugars;
```

Comment: Can u help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68493717/error-related-to-flutter-provider-package