# Flutter Error: Could not find the correct Provider<MyUser> above this SettingsForm Widget

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

When I run my flutter project it shows this in my debug console:

**Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this SettingsForm Widget**

Debug Console :

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<MyUser> above this SettingsForm Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice.
```

I am using a setting widget in my app. I think it is because I haven't put the widget as an ancestor of the provider.

My setting.dart code looks like this:

```
class SettingsForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsFormState createState() => _SettingsFormState();
}

class _SettingsFormState extends State<SettingsForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final List<String> sugars = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'];
  final List<int> strengths = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900];

  // form values
  String? _currentName;
  String? _currentSugars;
  int? _currentStrength;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MyUser user = Provider.of<MyUser>(context);

    return StreamBuilder<UserData>(
        stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            UserData? userData = snapshot.data;
            return Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Update your brew settings.',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                  TextFormField(
                    initialValue: userData!.name,
                    decoration: textInputDecoration,
                    validator: (val) =>
                        val!.isEmpty ? 'Please enter a name' : null,
                    onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentName = val),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                    value: _currentSugars ?? userData.sugars,
                    decoration: textInputDecoration,
                    items: sugars.map((sugar) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: sugar,
                        child: Text('$sugar sugars'),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentSugars = val),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  Slider(
                    value: (_currentStrength ?? userData.strength).toDouble(),
                    activeColor:
                        Colors.brown[_currentStrength ?? userData.strength],
                    inactiveColor:
                        Colors.brown[_currentStrength ?? userData.strength],
                    min: 100.0,
                    max: 900.0,
                    divisions: 8,
                    onChanged: (val) =>
                        setState(() => _currentStrength = val.round()),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                      style:
                          ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.pink[400]),
                      child: Text(
                        'Update',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(
                              _currentSugars ?? snapshot.data!.sugars,
                              _currentName ?? snapshot.data!.name,
                              _currentStrength ?? snapshot.data!.strength);
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        }
                      }),
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Loading();
          }
        });
  }
}
```

main.dart:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<MyUser?>.value(
      initialData: null,
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Anyone knows how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

add this in main.dart

```
  Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: MyUser(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

make file for provider

```
class MyUser extends ChangeNotifier {

// your code
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: where do i make file for provider

Comment: create new folder provider and inside the folder dart file name providers.dart

Comment: can i return stream provider there